# file_get_contents(C:\Users\dell\Documents\accounts\gna\public/storage/img/RsNR7dEIisWrF30dhrys.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to the Laravel framework. I wrote this code following what I saw in a tutorial. I've tried to change the image upload path but still end up with the same result. How can I solve this problem please?

```
    public function change()
    {
        #Get auth user
        $user = auth()->user();

        $avatar = $this->avatar->store('img'); #Save avatar image
        
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/storage/$avatar"; #Take the avatar's path
        $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); #Get avatar image type
        $image = file_get_contents($path); #Get the avatar image
        $avatarBase64 = "data:image/$type;base64,".base64_encode($image); #Convert avatar image to base64
        Storage::delete($avatar); #Delete the avatar image from the server as it is no longer needed

        $user->avatar = $avatarBase64;
        $user->save();

        session()->flash('success', 'Avatar successfully changed!');
        return redirect()->route('settings');
    }
```

Comment: use `storage_path()` for your `$path` variable: `$path = storage_path($avatar);`

Comment: Thanks tried it but still not working.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but you did verify that the file is physically available at that location, yes? Maybe it is not your 'get' that's the problem, but the 'store'?

Comment: Yeah, the file is physically available at that location, I believe the request wasn't being carried out due to a change in Oss. So I modified the above code to what's below. It might be of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem above as follows;

```
 public function change()
    {
        #Get auth user
        $user = auth()->user();

        //get img and save
        $avatarFile = $this->avatar->store('img');
        //get ext
        $type = pathinfo($avatarFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //Convert to base64
        $avatarBase64 = "data:image/$type;base64," . base64_encode(Storage::get($avatarFile));
        //Delete the product image from the server as it is no longer needed
        Storage::delete($avatarFile);

        //Store base64
        $user->avatar = $avatarBase64;
        $user->save();
        session()->flash('success', 'Avatar successfully changed!');
        return redirect()->route('settings');
    }
```

`$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/storage/$avatar";` This is where my problem was since I was running script in dev mode. Laravel simply couldn't properly determine the location of my script. Since the main goal is to store the image in base64 and delete original file I just removed the `$path` variable. The later would work in a production env I presume.

Comment: Great that you solved your issue and posted your solution. But can you please give more details what exactly was the issue and the change? Simply comparing a block of lines as a human being is not easy...

Comment: `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/storage/$avatar"; #Take the avatar's path` This is where my problem was since I was running script in dev mode. Laravel simply couldn't properly determine the location of my script. Since the main goal is to store the image in base64 and delete original file I just removed the `$path` variable. The later would work in a production env I presume.

Comment: Awesome, please don't write this in a comment (only) but add it to your answer. IMHO you should be able to edit your answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll do just that.